# How to use querySelector to remove a specific element from a list?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-listener

I set up a webpage with two headings, and two buttons. The webpage looks exactly like the following before pressing on anything:

Counter-1 : (somenumber)

[Increment Button] || [Decrement Nutton]

---

If I click on the first button, the somenumber **increments** by 1.
If I click on the second button, the somenumber **decrements** by 1.

In addition, when I click on the first button(increment-button), a list-item **gets added** to the webpage. When I click on the second button(decrement-button), the last added list-item **gets removed** from the webpage.

Both buttons work and do their purpose (incrementing/decremnting wise), and when I click on the first button, a list-item indeed gets added to the webpage.

The problem occurs when I try to remove the last added list item, by pressing the second button, as described.

This is the html section. Nothing out of the ordinary. One heading, and two buttons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Counter-1: <span id="counter-one">0</span></h1>
    <button id="increment">Increment Number</button>

    <button id="decrement">Decrement Number</button>

    <ul id="list-items"></ul>

    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the JavaScript section. I get the two buttons from the HTML document, I set up an empty list on the HTML document, which I wanted to fill with one list-item per click on the first button (using javascript, hence making the button interactive).

```
const incrementButton = document.getElementById("increment");
const decrementButton = document.getElementById("decrement");
const listOfItems = document.getElementById("list-items");

const counterValue = document.getElementById("counter-one");
let counter = 0;

function incrementValue() {
  counter++;
  counterValue.innerText = counter;

  //add a list item
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = "<b>Something</b> " + counter;
  li.setAttribute("data-counter", counter);
  listOfItems.appendChild(li);
  console.log(li);
}

function decrementValue() {
  counter--;
  counterValue.innerText = counter;
  //remove a list item
  const li = listOfItems.querySelector("[data-counter = " + counter + "]");

  li.remove();
}

incrementButton.addEventListener("click", incrementValue);
decrementButton.addEventListener("click", decrementValue);
```

The mechanism of incrementing and decrementing the value is **working properly**, and the appending of the list-items **works as well**, as mentioned.

But the lines:

```
listOfItems.querySelector("[data-counter = " + counter + "]");

li.remove();
```

used to "catch" the last added list-item,

are causing the following error:
`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '[data-counter = 1]' is not a valid selector. at HTMLButtonElement.decrementValue`

And I don't understand why the querySelector is invalid. I am certain that I have written something incorrect, or perhaps, an obsolete statement. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `counter` should be wrapped in quotes (and no blank spaces!) when used in data attribute selector. Use instead [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
ulElement.querySelector(`[data-counter="${counter}"]`);
```

or, if you insist in double quotes escape them with backslash like:

```js
ulElement.querySelector("[data-counter=\""+ counter +"\"]");
```

or, use single quotes to preserve double quotes like:

```js
ulElement.querySelector('[data-counter="'+ counter +'"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is off just a bit.  You had

```
ulElement.querySelector("[data-counter = " + counter + "]")
```

but it needs to have quotes around the value added like this, and probably remove the spaces around the `=` as well

```
ulElement.querySelector("[data-counter='" + counter + "']")
```

```js
const incrementButton = document.getElementById("increment");
const decrementButton = document.getElementById("decrement");
const ulElement = document.getElementById("list-items");

let counter = 0;

function incrementCounter() {
  const counterInc = document.getElementById("counter-one");
  counter++;
  counterInc.innerText = counter;

  //create an element
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.setAttribute("data-counter", counter);
  li.innerHTML = "<b>Something</b> " + counter;
  console.log(li);

  //append it to the list
  ulElement.appendChild(li);
}

function decrementCounter() {
  //remove an element
  const li = ulElement.querySelector("[data-counter='" + counter + "']");
  li.remove();

  const counterDec = document.getElementById("counter-two");
  counter--;
  counterDec.innerText = counter;
}

incrementButton.addEventListener("click", incrementCounter);
decrementButton.addEventListener("click", decrementCounter);
```

```html
<h1>Counter-1: <span id="counter-one">0</span></h1>
<button id="increment">click me</button>

<h1>Counter-2: <span id="counter-two">0</span></h1>
<button id="decrement">click me</button>

<ul id="list-items"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding quotation marks before and after the `counter` variable appears to fix the query selector error. Change the line to 1 of the 3 lines below:

```
const li = ulElement.querySelector('[data-counter = "' + counter + '"]');
```

```
const li = ulElement.querySelector("[data-counter = '" + counter + "']");
```

```
const li = ulElement.querySelector("[data-counter = \"" + counter + "\"]");
```

You could also use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), as mentioned by Roko C. Buljan above.

Answer (score 1):

Improved it by making it more organized and efficient by breaking it down into smaller functions for specific tasks, for a simple counter & list to be created/updated dynamically as the user interacts with it.

```js
const counterElement = document.querySelector("#counter-one");
let counter = 0;

const incrementCounter = () => {
    counter++;
    counterElement.innerText = counter;
    addLiElement();
}

const addLiElement = () => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.dataset.counter = counter;
    li.innerHTML = `<b>Something</b> ${counter}`;
    console.log(li);
    document.querySelector("#list-items").append(li);
}

const decrementCounter = () => {
    const li = document.querySelector(`#list-items [data-counter="${counter}"]`);
    if (li) {
        li.remove();
        counter--;
        counterElement.innerText = counter;
    }
}

document.querySelector("#increment").addEventListener("click", incrementCounter);
document.querySelector("#decrement").addEventListener("click", decrementCounter);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Counter-1: <span id="counter-one">0</span></h1>
    <button id="increment">Increment Number</button>

    <button id="decrement">Decrement Number</button>

    <ul id="list-items"></ul>

    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

it will run more smoothly and efficiently.

Comment: edited, now looks more better